# entry is hidden by keyboard on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm facing the problem that I have entries at the bottom of the screen, which when the keyboard pops ups it completely hides the entry while the user is typing the values, and that only happens on iOS. I tried to use scrollview, but still didn't work.

```
<ContentView.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout Margin="0,0,30,0">
            <Entry
                x:Name="searchBar"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,AutoSize"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                HeightRequest="40"
                Placeholder="Enter sensor"
                TextChanged="SearchBar_OnTextChanged"
                TextColor="{DynamicResource RelogixDarkGray}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <ListView
                x:Name="dataListView"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="5,40,.98,.4"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                IsVisible="False"
                ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout Margin="5" Padding="0">
                                <Label
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource NormalFont}"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    Text="{Binding .}"
                                    TextColor="#FF464859"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

[this is the entry before the keyboard pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57sal.jpg)

[This is when the keyboard pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAkpI.jpg)

Comment: What would be the desired UI/UX experience? Would the Entry be pushed up by the keyboard? In that case, hardly nothing of the underlying ListView would be visible.

Comment: @MouseOnMars I did include the screenshots of the UI at the bottom of the code

Comment: You showed screenshot before the keyboard flies out and then when it hides the entry. However, I don't understand what is the behavior (UI) you want to see? With other words, if the keyboard is shown how is the UI supposed to look?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution used in my project , you can have a check this whether be helpful for you .

Using `Focused/UnFocused` method of `Entry` in Xamarin Forms , to know whether the keyboard shows. Then you can detail with the view of Entry to move to the above of Keyboard by using **[TranslateTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#translation)** animation to implement it .

Here is the **Xaml** code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="AppkeyboardHideEntryInIOS.MainPage">

    <StackLayout x:Name="MainLayout" Padding="20">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Entry x:Name="myEntry" Placeholder="Entry" Focused="myEntry_Focused" Unfocused="myEntry_Unfocused"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

`Focused/UnFocused` in **ContentPage** as follow :

```
private void myEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    // Decete whethe in iOS platform
    if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
    {
        // belong to iPhone X seriors device , the height of keyboard is 333
        if (Height > 800)
        {
            // check whether entry need to tarnslate
            if (Height - myEntry.Y - myEntry.Height < 333)
            {
                myEntry.TranslateTo(0, -333, 50);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // belong to iPhone 6,7,8 seriors device, the height of keyboard is 258
            // check whether entry need to tarnslate
            if (Height - myEntry.Y - myEntry.Height < 258)
            {
                myEntry.TranslateTo(0, -258, 50);
            }
        }
    }

}

private void myEntry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    // Decete whethe in iOS platform
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("unFocused");
        myEntry.TranslateTo(0, 0, 50);
    }
}
```

Then you will see the effect as follow :

[image]